# Obtain youtube username from google Plus api - access token scope insufficientPermissions

Tags: youtube-api, google-api, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to get Youtube username via google plus api. I use php Services from Plus ang YT api and I'm using symfony 2. Obtaining access token works ok, and i'm not going to put it here.
There is also no problem with google plus service, after authorization i'm getting all the information that i need. In YT case, i'm getting error :
insufficientPermissions error
So i check my access token scope in here:
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
and scope of my Access token is only for Google Plus, i'm not able to force the google Api php clinet to make the YT scope aviable too.
Any ideas?

Here is my code :

```
require_once '../src/google_api_php_client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once '../src/google_api_php_client/src/contrib/Google_PlusService.php';
require_once '../src/google_api_php_client/src/contrib/Google_YouTubeService.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus');

$youtube = new Google_YouTubeService($client);

if(!empty($allR['code'])){
    $client->setClientId('clientIDxxx');
    $client->setClientSecret('SecretXXX');  
    $client->setRedirectUri('postmessage');
    $client->authenticate($allR['code']);
    $token = json_decode($client->getAccessToken()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you enabled YouTube Data API v3 rom your [devconsole](https://code.google.com/apis/console).

Then instead of setting scopes, try setting client id and secret from [devconsole](https://code.google.com/apis/console).

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
    FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);

// YouTube object used to make all Data API requests.
$youtube = new Google_YoutubeService($client);

$plus = new $youtube = new Google_PlusService($client);
```